# How to get nodejs to return something other than object promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my user.js file I have a async function to retrieve the avatar location from the database as follows:

```
async findavatar(username) {
        const sql = `SELECT image FROM users WHERE user = "${username}";`
        const db = await sqlite.open(dbName)
        const location = await this.db.get(sql)
        await db.close()
        console.log(location)
        return location
    }
```

I call it in the index.js file:

```
router.get('/', async ctx => {
    try {
        if(ctx.session.authorised !== true) return ctx.redirect('/login?msg=you need to log in')
        const data = {}
        const user = await new User(dbName)
        const currentuser = ctx.session.loggeduser
        const avatarlocation = user.findavatar(currentuser)
        console.log('location of avatar:' + avatarlocation)
        if(ctx.query.msg) data.msg = ctx.query.msg
        await ctx.render('newarticle', {location: currentuser })
    } catch(err) {
        await ctx.render('error', {message: err.message})
    }
})
```

The console.log in user file works and displays the location but when I get to the index.js file and run it gives a promise.
When I run the page to retrieve the location I get [object Promise] as a result, how do I get it to show the value pulled from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `await` before calling `user.findavatar(currentuser)`

```js
const avatarlocation = await user.findavatar(currentuser)
```

Comment: If i do that I get the result [object object], any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: That can be because the avatarlocation object can be too long for the console. Try `JSON.stringify(avatarlocation)` to see the response

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(avatarlocation))`

Comment: Thanks mate. This fixed the problem, strange had been stuck on it for a while

Answer (score 1):

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

You can read about it [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

You need to call `.then()` to resolve the Promise.

Example:

```
avatarlocation.then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your `findavatar` function returns a promise because it has async keywords. in order to get value, you will need to resolve promise by using either await keyword or .then method
value, you will need to await for

```
router.get('/', async ctx => {
  try {
    if(ctx.session.authorised !== true) return ctx.redirect('/login?msg=you need to log in')
    const data = {}
    const user = await new User(dbName)
    ...
    const avatarlocation = await user.findavatar(currentuser)
    console.log('location of avatar:' + avatarlocation)
    ..
} catch(err) {
    await ctx.render('error', {message: err.message})
}
})
```

Comment: once i do this i get this in the terminal ```location of avatar:[object Object]```

Comment: check for this line ```const location = await this.db.get(sql)``` whats output of this line ?